# Access parent controller from the child state

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a controller in AngluarJS defined like so:

```
'use strict';

var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller('AppCtrl', ['sth',
    function (sth) {
        this.inverse = false;
    }
]);
```

here is routes deffinition:

```
$stateProvider.
state('app', {
    abstract: true,
    templateUrl: 'app/views/layout.html',
    controller: 'AppCtrl',
    controllerAs: 'app',
    resolve: {}
}).
state('app.settings', {
    abstract: true,
    url: '/settings',
    template: '<ui-view/>',
    onEnter: function () {

    }
});
```

How to access inverse variable from AppCtrl in app.settings route?

Comment: If you want to share data between 2 controllers, a service/factory is your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share data between 2 controllers, a service/factory is your best bet. Below is a an example of how you would do it. I have written it free-hand, so there may be syntax errors, but you get the idea.

```
app.controller('AppCtrl', ['sth', 'SharedData',
    function (sth, SharedData) {
        SharedData.inverse = false;
    }
]);

app.factory('SharedDate', function() {
  var data = {
     inverse: true  // or whatever default value you want to set
  };

  return data;
})
```

Now, you can inject SharedData factory in any controller, where you want to use that data.

Comment: I know I can use service but I feel like it is an overkill for only variable change. If I would use $scope.inverse instead of this.inverse it would be accessible from the children scope. I am wondreing if it possible doing the same in my approach.

Comment: Another way is to set it on rootScope but I personally never do that. I would still go down the factory route. That way it will be useful in case you have to share more data in the future.